# How delete object in array Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have an object:

```
$scope.obj = {
  name : "ok",
  list : [{object},{object2}]
}
```

So, I have `{object1}`. How can I remove this object from `list` if I dont know key?

My code is:

```
var indexToDelete = list.people.keys(item);
console.log(indexToDelete);
delete list.people[indexToDelete];
```

Item is:

```
Object
$$hashKey:
"object:29"
artist:""
cover:""
song:"Basta 1"
source:""
type:"9"
```

Comment: Your list is an array, so to delete any element you can use splice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: use the $index of ng-repeat, and use splice() to remove the selected index...

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly {object1} is?  As in, is it literally a reference to the same object that is inside `list[]`? Or do you need to determine whether one of the objects in `list[]` just has the same properties and values as {object1}?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Comment: I added object in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to simplify your data structure just a bit, for clarity.  I'm also going to assume that the `$$hashKey` can be used to determine whether the object to be removed is the same as one in the list -- if that's not the case, and we need to compare all the keys and parameters within the objects, the answer gets quite a bit more [complex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects).

Given those assumptions, here is a vanilla javascript version that should work in all current browsers:

```js
var list = [
    {$$hashKey: 1,  artist: "Alice"},
    {$$hashKey: 42, artist: "Bob"},
    {$$hashKey: 25, artist: "Charlie"}
];

var itemToRemove = {$$hashKey: 42, artist: "Bob"};

for (var i=0; i<list.length;i++) {
  if (list[i].$$hashKey == itemToRemove.$$hashKey) {
    list.splice(i,1); // removes the matched element
    i = list.length;  // break out of the loop. Not strictly necessary
  }
}

console.log(list);
```

You could simplify that somewhat if `itemToRemove` is a reference to an object that is in the list; in that case you can just compare them directly instead of depending on `$$hashKey`:

```js
var obj1 = {$$hashKey: 1,  artist: "Alice"},
    obj2 = {$$hashKey: 42, artist: "Bob"},
    obj3 = {$$hashKey: 25, artist: "Charlie"};

var list = [obj1, obj2, obj3];
var itemToRemove = obj2;

for (var i=0; i<list.length;i++) {
  if (list[i] === itemToRemove) {
    list.splice(i,1); // removes the matched element
    i = list.length;  // break out of the loop. Not strictly necessary
  }
}

console.log(list);
```

(If you are transpiling from ES6 there are quite a few new convenience methods available so that you don't need to iterate through the array manually: `array.prototype.findIndex`, `array.prototype.filter` for example, but these are not currently supported in enough browsers to be usable in production.   Alternatively, if you are willing to add a library such as underscore.js, you could use `_.without()` to remove specific elements.)

Answer (score 0):

Try array [**splice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

The **`splice()`** method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

**Working demo :**

```js
var obj = {
    name : "ok",
    list : [
          {"name":"abc"},
          {"name":"xyz"}
    ]
}

obj.list.splice(0, 1); 

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two case 
 1. If you have already value  as same as you want remove from array  then do this

```
  $scope.obj = {
    name : "ok",
    list : [{object},{object2}]
    }
    var index  =$scope.obj.list.indexOf({object});
    $scope.obj.list.splice(index,1);
```

2. If it is fix that you want to remove first element of array then do         this

```
$scope.obj.list.splice(0,1);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the `delete` keyword and then the property which needs to be deleted.

So, if you need to delete `Object1`, Firstly, using the `findIndex` method find the index in the list and then you can use `delete`.

`var indexToDelete = $scope.obj.list.findIndex(YourCriteria);
 delete $scope.obj.list[indexToDelete];`

Note: `findIndex` is part of the ES7 Draft specification, so certain browsers might not support this method.

**Edit1:**
To bring more clarity, the `findIndex` method takes a callback which is called for each value in the Array.

Comment: I get an error: `TypeError: #<Object> is not a function
    at Array.findIndex (native)`. Here: `var indexToDelete = list.people.findIndex(item);
                    delete list.people[indexToDelete];`

Comment: $scope.obj.list is: `Array[3]
0
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:31"
artist
:
""
cover
:
""
song
:
"dnd-callback Custom callback that is passed to dropzone callbacks and can be used to communicate between source and target scopes. The dropzone can pass user defined variables to this callback. This can be used to transfer objects without serialization, see Demo."
source
:
""
type
:
"9"`

Comment: `findIndex` is not really usable at this time; "Certain browsers might not support this" in this case means any version of IE.  This answer also glosses over the fact that `YourCriteria` needs to be a function, not an object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: (not to mention that function would have to contain code for "are these objects equal", which is the nontrivial part of the question...)

Comment: @DanielBeck, i did not mention anywhere the `yourCriteri`a is an object. Also, the OP has not originally posted a lot of code but just the first code block. This answer should provide a direction how to proceed further to look for an answer.

Comment: @Agalo You didn't mention anything at all about `yourCriteria`, hence the confusion in @Darama's first two comments above. "a direction how to proceed further to look for an answer" is not really much of an answer.